# For loop Testing in java

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

```
 public void numberOfChoices() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int guess = scan.nextInt();


    }

}
```

how can i test this for loop in junit. my method should be void.
i think i couldn't make myself clear. my question is that how can i test the loop that actually it goes ten time? i hope you understand now. but i don't know some people just try to be oversmart and give negative point to my question i think if you couldn't understand ask for more explanation. and this is question is not that simple to solve too so don't understand why i got negative....

Comment: What do you want to test in the above loop? What is num in that for loop?

Comment: i just need to test for loop that actually goes 10 times

Answer (score 1):

Writing code easily to test is the first step for writing test.

Every single method should have their meaning and only do one thing.

If you face problem in writing test, you might think about it.

Answer (score 1):

If your method must be *void* and you don't work with database I would advise to create getters for the variables that you want to verify. For the loop you might want to have some `Array` or `List`, for example, and then in your test do something like this:

```
assertEquals(expectedList, yourClass.getList);
```

However, it is not the ideal scenario because you should not change the production code to fit your testing needs. If you work with database then create a separate query in the test to fetch the needed data.